# "Unable to mount location. Failed to mount Windows share" error when trying to share folders

Tags: shared-folders

I have two Ubuntu machines both on 11.10

I want to share folders from one to the other.

If, on the server machine, (in Nautilus) I right click on the folders and click Properties> Share > Share this folder > Create share.

Then on the client I'm prompted for a username and password. My username and password does not work.

If I select "Guest access" check box then I get "Unable to mount location. Failed to mount Windows share"

This should be straightforward, right?

Comment: It should be straight forward and all mine have been. I often setup my music/video collection for everyone at home to share. Have you installed SAMBA yet? I don't mean the program in the software center either I mean terminal "sudo apt-get install samba"

Comment: Yes installing samba seemed to fix the issue. Thanks. I just wish there was an error message that made sense.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and found that it was because of permissions on folders above the one that I was trying to share.

For example if you are trying to share:

```
/media/shared/music
```

Check that the permissions of the `/media` and `/media/shared` folders are 755 (`drwxr-xr-x`) or similar that allows the group and others to execute (open) the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

As I can see from your description you want to share a directory.
Since you use Windows 8 and I can see the "Security" tab you are using NTFS-filesystem.
It seems like you didn´t configure NTFS-permissions.

```
Click on the "Security" Tab of the Folder you want to share.
Then "Edit..."
In the new window click "Add..."
In the new window click "Advanced..."
In the new window click "Find Now..."
Select the user who needs the permission to acces the folder.
Go back to the "Permissions for " dialog.
Choose the user you added.
Set permission to "Allow" / Full controll (Or at least read permission)
Click Apply.
```

On the sharing tab, the only entry you Need is:

```
Everyone
With permission "Full Controll".
```

You can manage the permissions with the NTFS-Permissions of the Security Tab.

The rest of the configuration looks correct.

Worked for me